# Can Terraform pull down the newest state file by itself?

Tags: terraform

We started using Terraform to create VMs in some Cloud Providers.

But we are a team with several people.

Terraform has a state file.

Whenever someone changes something via Terraform, ex.: creating, decomming VMs, that state file need to be again sent to the others too, or else, when the others open their terraform, it will re-create the decommed VMs or destroy existing ones since they had old state file.

**My question:** Can Terraform pull down the newest state file by itself? Or manually, before doing anything, humans needs to be trusted to "always download the newest state file"? Humans will make mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use remote state storage like [S3](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html)?

Also you can use [Terraform Cloud](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/index.html) to organzie workflow and have the shared state.